# Under what circumstances would AssertEquals fail when the actual and expected values match?

Tags: java, junit4, android-testing

I have a test case for an Android app that verifies the time in a video player activity does not change when the user fast-forwards and rewinds the video by 15 seconds. The test works like this:

1. Open the video player and let the video play for a few seconds.
2. Pause the video and check the timestamp.
3. Press the "fast forward 15 seconds" button followed by the "rewind 15 seconds" button.
4. Check that the new timestamp is the same.

The timestamp is in hh:mm:ss format. I use the following method to get the play time in seconds:

```
    private int getPlayTime() {
        String timestamp = getTimestamp();
        return Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(0, 2)) * 3600 +
                Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(3, 5)) * 60 +
                Integer.parseInt(timestamp.substring(6)) ;
    }
```

`getTimestamp()` gets the timestamp string from an Android view:

```
    private String getTimestamp() {
        AppCompatTextView playTime = (AppCompatTextView) solo.getView(/* View ID */);
        return (String) playTime.getText();
    }
```

And here is the assert statement:

```
assertEquals("Rewinding should bring us back 15 seconds. Start = " + startTime + ", end = " + endTime, startTime, endTime);
```

Although the values are the same, `AssertEquals()` sometimes returns a failure: `java.lang.AssertionError: Time should advance by 15 seconds. Start = 37, end = 37`

This happens less than 10% of the time and not easily reproducible. I'm completely lost for an explanation. Could this be a JUnit bug?

Comment: This message is not about rewind, but about advance.It's a different assert

Comment: Can you confirm that the `hh:mm:ss` timestamp strings are identical?

Comment: @csum: I'm pretty sure they're the same.

Comment: What is the type of startTime and endTime? Of they are strings, is there any chance they contain non-printable characters? Are they differing types with the `toString()`s that produce the same output?

Comment: "I use the following method to get the play time in seconds:" so `01:02:03` is a play time of 6 seconds?

Comment: Looks like I forgot to multiply the hours by 3,600 and minutes by 60. D'oh!
However, this hadn't affected my tests yet because the videos are very short.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion seems to be coming from some other test case, triggered when forward button is clicked, based on your description.

Comment: I'm actually comparing against the starting value. Sorry the description wasn't very accurate. It should probably say something like "Current timestamp should match starting value" instead.